# Exclude third party libraries from analysis

Tags: azure-application-insights

We have **Application Insights** to profile and measure our application, but it's registering exceptions in third party libraries, making noise to the analysis, so I'd like to tell Application Insights what assemblies to exclude from the analysis.

I've checked the [ApplicationInsights.config documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-configuration-with-applicationinsights-config) but I didn't see anything related to that.

So, is it possible to exclude dlls from the analysis?

Comment: Asking for meta-help on a question is not productive.  It will more likely than not have the opposite effect of what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of filters you can use a `TelemetryProcessor`. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling):

> To filter telemetry, you write a telemetry processor and register it with the SDK. All telemetry goes through your processor, and you can choose to drop it from the stream, or add properties. This includes telemetry from the standard modules such as the HTTP request collector and the dependency collector, as well as telemetry you have written yourself.

You can write a like this:

```
public class ExceptionFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor next { get; set; }

    public ExceptionFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        var exceptionTelemetry = item as ExceptionTelemetry;
        if(exceptionTelemetry == null || 
          !exceptionTelemetry.Exception.StackTrace.Contains("NameOfThirdPartyApp"))
            next.Process(item);
    }
}
```

I leave it up to your imagination what the best way is to identify those 3rd party app exceptions.